# Finding the voltage across the resistor and the phase angle for Vs

Tags: voltage, resistors, kirchhoffs-laws, phasor

I used KVL to find the voltage across the resistor but how could I solve this if the phasor angle Vs is unknown? So far I only got the solution up until the equation for KVL which is

$$ V_s - V_l - V_R = 0 $$
$$V_R = V_S - V_L $$

how do you also find the phase angle of the voltage source?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, notice that the absolute value of the current through the resistor is given by:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left|\text{I}_\text{R}\right|&=\left|\frac{\text{V}_\text{R}}{\text{R}}\right|\\
\\
&=\frac{\left|\text{V}_\text{R}\right|}{\left|\text{R}\right|}\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{\text{R}}\cdot\left|\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}\space\text{||}\space\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}{\displaystyle\left(\text{R}\space\text{||}\space\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\right)+\text{j}\omega\text{L}}\cdot\text{V}_\text{s}\right|\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{\text{R}}\cdot\left|\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}{\displaystyle\text{R}+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}}{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}{\displaystyle\text{R}+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}}\cdot\text{V}_\text{s}\right|\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{\text{R}}\cdot\left|\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}{\displaystyle\text{R}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}+\left(\text{R}+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\right)\text{j}\omega\text{L}}\cdot\text{V}_\text{s}\right|\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{\text{R}}\cdot\left|\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}}{\displaystyle\text{R}+\left(\text{j}\omega\text{C}\text{R}+1\right)\text{j}\omega\text{L}}\right|\cdot\left|\text{V}_\text{s}\right|\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{\text{R}}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\left|\text{R}\right|}{\displaystyle\left|\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{C}\text{R}\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right|}\cdot\left|\text{V}_\text{s}\right|\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{\text{R}}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}}{\displaystyle\left|\text{R}-\text{CLR}\omega^2+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right|}\cdot\left|\text{V}_\text{s}\right|\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\left|\text{R}-\text{CLR}\omega^2+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right|}\cdot\left|\text{V}_\text{s}\right|\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\left|\text{V}_\text{s}\right|}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\left(\text{R}-\text{CLR}\omega^2\right)^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\left|\text{V}_\text{s}\right|}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\left(\text{R}\left(1-\text{CL}\omega^2\right)\right)^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2}}
\end{split}\tag1
\end{equation}

Where \$\alpha\space\text{||}\space\beta:=\frac{\displaystyle\alpha\beta}{\displaystyle\alpha+\beta}\$.

We can do the same thing for the current through the capacitor and see that:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left|\text{I}_\text{C}\right|&=\frac{\displaystyle\omega\text{CR}\left|\text{V}_\text{s}\right|}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\left(\text{R}\left(1-\text{CL}\omega^2\right)\right)^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2}}
\end{split}\tag2
\end{equation}

The absolute value of the voltage across the inductor is given by:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left|\text{V}_\text{L}\right|&=\left|\text{j}\omega\text{L}\cdot\text{I}_\text{L}\right|\\
\\
&=\left|\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right|\cdot\left|\text{I}_\text{in}\right|\\
\\
&=\omega\text{L}\cdot\left|\frac{\text{V}_\text{s}}{\text{Z}_\text{in}}\right|\\
\\
&=\omega\text{L}\cdot\frac{\left|\text{V}_\text{s}\right|}{\left|\text{Z}_\text{in}\right|}\\
\\
&=\omega\text{L}\left|\text{V}_\text{s}\right|\cdot\left|\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\left(\text{R}\space\text{||}\space\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\right)\right|^{-1}\\
\\
&=\omega\text{L}\left|\text{V}_\text{s}\right|\cdot\left|\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}{\displaystyle\text{R}+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}\right|^{-1}\\
\\
&=\omega\text{L}\left|\text{V}_\text{s}\right|\cdot\left|\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}}{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{CR}+1}\right|^{-1}\\
\\
&=\omega\text{L}\left|\text{V}_\text{s}\right|\cdot\left|\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}}{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{CR}+1}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle1-\text{j}\omega\text{CR}}{\displaystyle1-\text{j}\omega\text{CR}}\right|^{-1}\\
\\
&=\omega\text{L}\left|\text{V}_\text{s}\right|\cdot\left|\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}\left(1-\text{j}\omega\text{CR}\right)}{\displaystyle1+\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)^2}\right|^{-1}\\
\\
&=\omega\text{L}\left|\text{V}_\text{s}\right|\cdot\left|\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}}{\displaystyle1+\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)^2}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}-\frac{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{CR}^2}{\displaystyle1+\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)^2}\right|^{-1}\\
\\
&=\omega\text{L}\left|\text{V}_\text{s}\right|\cdot\left|\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}}{\displaystyle1+\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)^2}+\omega\left(\text{L}-\frac{\displaystyle\text{CR}^2}{\displaystyle1+\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)^2}\right)\text{j}\right|^{-1}\\
\\
&=\omega\text{L}\left|\text{V}_\text{s}\right|\cdot\left(\sqrt{\left(\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}}{\displaystyle1+\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)^2}\right)^2+\left(\omega\left(\text{L}-\frac{\displaystyle\text{CR}^2}{\displaystyle1+\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)^2}\right)\right)^2}\right)^{-1}
\end{split}\tag3
\end{equation}

Using your given values, we find:

$$\text{C}=\frac{1}{4000}\space\text{F}\space,\space\text{L}=\frac{1}{5}\space\text{H}\space,\space\text{R}=30\space\Omega\tag4$$

Comment: Is Vr in the equation the voltage division for the resistor???

Comment: @mamab yes indeed.

Comment: The way the problemis presented, the solution should be using phasors.